# Color transition flickering in Processing using my own stage system

Tags: java, animation, processing

I'm experimenting with Processing, i've written a very simple stage system for my project. I have 3 stages:
0 - lasts 2 seconds, grey screen
1 - lasts 1 second, transition from black to white
2 - lasts 2 seconds, transition from white to black

Stages 1 and 2 repeat over and over and sometimes between the last frame of either stage and the first frame of the next stage, screen flickers (i think you'll it see for yourself).

```
package ryby;

import java.awt.Color;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class Ryby extends PApplet {

    public static PApplet APPLET;
    public static final int X = 700;
    public static final int Y = 465;

    int counter;
    int state = 0;
    int substate = 0;

    StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        APPLET = this;
        frameRate(60);
        smooth();
        size(X, Y, JAVA2D);
        counter = millis();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        title.delete(0, title.length());
        title.append("Ryby - ").append(state).append(" ").append(substate)
                .append(" ").append(frameRate);
        frame.setTitle(title.toString());
        Color color = new Color(get(0, 0));
        System.out.println(color);
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                intro();
                break;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String _args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[]{ryby.Ryby.class.getName()});
    }

    void intro() {
        System.out.println(substate);
        System.out.println(millis() - counter);
        switch (substate) {
            case 0:
                setSubState(2000, 1);
                break;
            case 1:
                background((millis() - counter) * 255 / 1000);
                setSubState(1000, 2);

                break;
            case 2:
                background(255 - (millis() - counter) * 255 / 2000);
                setSubState(2000, 1);

                break;
        }

    }

    void setState(int ms, int s) {
        if (millis() >= counter + ms) {
            state = s;
            counter = millis();
        }
    }

    void setSubState(int ms, int s) {

        if (millis() >= counter + ms) {
            substate = s;
            counter = millis();

        }

    }
}
```

I know that i'm making a silly mistake somewhere and I only need to find out where :)

Comment: The use of non-standard API's isn't going to help use answer your questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my problem

```
void intro() {
    System.out.println(substate);
    switch (substate) {
    case 0:
        setSubState(2000, 1);
        break;
    case 1:

        setSubState(1000, 2);
        if (substate == 1) {
            background(calc(1000, 256));
        }

        break;
    case 2:

        setSubState(2000, 1);
        if (substate == 2) {
            background(256 - calc(2000, 256));
        }

        break;
    }

}

int calc(int max, int val) {
    int r;
    if ((millis() - counter) > max) {
        r = val;
    } else {
        r = (millis() - counter) * val / max;
    }
    System.out.println(r);
    return r;

}

void setState(int ms, int s) {
    if (millis() >= counter + ms) {
        state = s;
        counter = millis();
    }
}

void setSubState(int ms, int s) {
    if (millis() >= counter + ms) {
        substate = s;
        counter = millis();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have something to do with you dividing by integers when setting the background. Making them floats seems to fix it... Thus in intro() in switch (substate) {

instead of

```
background((millis() - counter) * 255 / 1000);
```

and

```
background(255 - (millis() - counter) * 255 / 2000);
```

do

```
background((millis() - counter) * 255 / 1000.0);
```

and

```
background(255 - (millis() - counter) * 255 / 2000.0);
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything